# Package of R for comparing graphs of daily activity of birds

Tags: r

I need to compare some (or at least two) graphs of activity of  birds, like in the example below.
Column “Hour” –  it’s a time  (8.25 = 8 h 15 min, 8.50 = 8h 30 min, 8.75 = 8h 45 min, etc; 
column R –  it’s a mean number of birds that were observed at this time in a month.

What package in R I can use for compare these curves with each other? By dint of this test I want to obtain answer: Do these graphs have a statistically significant difference? 
I found the division “Handling and Analyzing Spatio-Temporal Data”:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html

That has some special packages for the analysis of animal movements:  “**Moving objects, trajectories**” (that seems more suitable for my task ) and ”**Point patterns**” that also could be acceptable.
But which package  will be best? Maybe not from this list, probably I can use some common and more simple package?

Example of my data:

```
A                   B                   C   
Hours   R(Jan)     Hours    R(Jul)      Hours   R(Sept)
8.25    0.00        8.25    0.00        8.25    0.00
8.50    0.00        8.50    0.00        8.50    1.38
8.75    0.00        8.75    0.00        8.75    2.23
9.00    3.75        9.00    0.11        9.00    4.15
9.25    1.54        9.25    0.75        9.25    7.00
9.50    1.77        9.50    0.38        9.50    9.57
9.75    6.15        9.75    2.85        9.75    7.57
10.00   3.69        10.00   1.54        10.00   7.21
10.25   2.00        10.25   4.00        10.25   3.36
10.50   5.17        10.50   5.54        10.50   5.36
10.75   8.92        10.75   4.92        10.75   5.71
11.00   6.08        11.00   4.85        11.00   6.14
11.25   3.18        11.25   4.38        11.25   4.21
11.50   3.50        11.50   4.77        11.50   3.50
11.75   2.38        11.75   2.91        11.75   3.21
```

This question is a small part of the project. An example of plot (graph of activity for some month):
[https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10801618_995643917127882_5271235973091648468_n.jpg?oh=197eec09613197f338ee12dff02c2eb5&oe=54DFF8A5&**gda**=1427484793_acf67e6cc5f0bfb068c8bced67617384](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10801618_995643917127882_5271235973091648468_n.jpg?oh=197eec09613197f338ee12dff02c2eb5&oe=54DFF8A5&__gda__=1427484793_acf67e6cc5f0bfb068c8bced67617384)

Comment: This does not sound like a specific programming question. If you do not know what statistical method is appropriate for your data, you should post so [stats.se] instead to get statistical advice. Package recommendations are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I asked the same question in the Cross Validated, but then I found these packages and thought that will be best to ask about R packages here (in a special R forum). Ok, I'll try to repeat this question there again.


Could you advise me - where I can ask a tecnical question about Stack Exchange. I don't know how to create a table with separate columns in the post (as you did when corrected my post).

Comment: Just mark your data as a "code sample" in the editor (such that each row begins with four spaces).

Comment: Do you have a link to the CV question?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point for you question, but the p-value are not correct from the ks test, so something is amiss...

Data

```
txt = 
'Hours   R(Jan)     Hours    R(Jul)      Hours   R(Sept)
8.25    0.00        8.25    0.00        8.25    0.00
8.50    0.00        8.50    0.00        8.50    1.38
8.75    0.00        8.75    0.00        8.75    2.23
9.00    3.75        9.00    0.11        9.00    4.15
9.25    1.54        9.25    0.75        9.25    7.00
9.50    1.77        9.50    0.38        9.50    9.57
9.75    6.15        9.75    2.85        9.75    7.57
10.00   3.69        10.00   1.54        10.00   7.21
10.25   2.00        10.25   4.00        10.25   3.36
10.50   5.17        10.50   5.54        10.50   5.36
10.75   8.92        10.75   4.92        10.75   5.71
11.00   6.08        11.00   4.85        11.00   6.14
11.25   3.18        11.25   4.38        11.25   4.21
11.50   3.50        11.50   4.77        11.50   3.50
11.75   2.38        11.75   2.91        11.75   3.21'

df <- read.table(text=txt,header=T)
df<-df[,c(1,2,4,6)]
names(df) <- c('Hour','A.Count','B.Count','C.Count')
```

Here's a plot of the cumulative count raw data

```
plot(df$Hour,cumsum(df$A.Count),t='b',pch=2,
     xlab='Hour',ylab='Cummulative Count',ylim=c(0,80))
lines(df$Hour,cumsum(df$B.Count),t='b',pch=3)
lines(df$Hour,cumsum(df$C.Count),t='b',pch=4)
legend(8.5, 80, c("A", "B", "C"), pch = c(2, 3, 4), lty=c(1,1,1), merge=T)
```

[image]

It is easier to compare the normalized cumulative counts

```
plot(df$Hour,cumsum(df$A.Count)/sum(df$A.Count),t='b',pch=2,
     xlab='Hour',ylab='Normalized Cummulative Count',ylim=c(0,1))
lines(df$Hour,cumsum(df$B.Count)/sum(df$B.Count),t='b',pch=3)
lines(df$Hour,cumsum(df$C.Count)/sum(df$C.Count),t='b',pch=4)
legend(8.5, 1, c("A", "B", "C"), pch = c(2, 3, 4), lty=c(1,1,1), merge=T)
```

[image]

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test can be used to determine if two samples come from the same distribution.  Need to convert the frequency data into sample data.  You should use actual sampled data instead of generating the sampled data.

```
genHours <- function(rhv,rcv) {
  vec <- NULL
  for (is in seq(1,length(rhv))) {
    rh <- rhv[is]
    rc <- rcv[is]
    if (rc>0) {
      hs <- runif(rc,rh-0.24/2,rh+0.24/2)
      vec <- c(vec,hs)
    }
  }
  return(vec)
}
vecA <- genHours(df$Hour, df$A.Count*30)
vecB <- genHours(df$Hour, df$B.Count*30)
vecC <- genHours(df$Hour, df$C.Count*30)
```

Here's the KS test results.  The distance D compares with the figures, but the p values are too small.  Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check if the distributions come from the same distribution

```
cat("Comparing Groups A and B")
ks.test(vecA,vecB)
cat("Comparing Groups B and C")
ks.test(vecB,vecC)
cat("Comparing Groups A and C")
ks.test(vecA,vecC)
```

The output is

```
Comparing Groups A and B

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  vecA and vecB
D = 0.2004, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Comparing Groups B and C

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  vecB and vecC
D = 0.4032, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Comparing Groups A and C

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  vecA and vecC
D = 0.2092, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

From these values, you could conclude that the hypothesis that the samples came from the same distributions can be rejected.

The ks p-value for the two-sided test checks for equality and answers this question: "If the two samples were randomly sampled from identical populations, what is the probability that the two cumulative frequency distributions would be as far apart as observed? More precisely, what is the chance that the value of the Komogorov-Smirnov D statistic would be as large or larger than observed?"

If the ks P value is small, conclude that the two groups were sampled from populations with different distributions. The populations may differ in median, variability or the shape of the distribution.

Compare p values with the output from testing two normal distribution samples.  Here the p-value does not reject the two-sided or equality hypothesis

```
 ks.test(rnorm(50),rnorm(200))

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  rnorm(50) and rnorm(200)
D = 0.115, p-value = 0.6654
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Ref:

1) [Description of meaning of p value for Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?interpreting_results_kolmogorov-smirnov_test.htm)

2) [Description of ranges of p value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)

Comment: Thank you, I will repeat the ks-test (you didn’t put the result with the D and p-value here), but I understood the logic. But why do you think, that too small p-value says about the error in approach? I supposed that the smaller p-value, the better the test result?

Comment: The original post had duplicate values for the sample time, which violates the assumptions of the ks test.  The revised time estimates do not have duplicates (length(unique(vecA) == length(vecA)), but the p value is still small, indicating a strong probability to reject the hypothesis that the samples come from the same distribution.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to put all your data into one group, and then fit the (cummulative) distribution plot with one of the standard distributions.  Then you could fit the standard to the other distributions to observe the change in the coefficients of the standard.  Ref http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf or http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-distributions-to-data-with-r/

Comment: To better understand the ks test, in r, enter ks.test and press return to see the function.

Comment: Comparing *distributions* neglects all the temporal information, which is implicit in the request to compare "curves."